# Datatype mismatch (code 20) while inserting

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite, mismatch

In my project im using sqlite database to save pictures and their locations. i get this error while trying to insert the data into my database:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: [INSERT INTO PHOTO VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.tomer.finalproject, PID: 18550
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:786)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:926)
```

Here is my code:

the insert method which is inside the class called SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public void insertData(String name, String lat, String lon, byte[] image) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO PHOTO VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindString(1, name);
        statement.bindString(2, lat);
        statement.bindString(3, lon);
        statement.bindBlob(4, image);

        statement.executeInsert();

}
```

I call this in a button 'add' from another activity :

Those 2 lines are under onCreate

```
sqLiteHelper=new SQLiteHelper(this,"GalleryDB.sqlite",null,1);
        sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PHOTO (name VARCHAR,lat VARCHAR,lon VARCHAR,image BLOG,Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT)");
```

and this is my add Button:

```
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
               Location l = g.getLocation();
                if (l != null) {
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lon = l.getLongitude();
                     String stLat= String.valueOf(lat);
                     String stLon= String.valueOf(lon);
                    try{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved To Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 sqLiteHelper.insertData(etname.getText().toString().trim(),stLat.trim(),stLon.trim(),imageViewToByte(imageView));

                   }
                    catch (Exception e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


                }
        });
```

Just want to point out that everything was working until my Laptop crushed and i had to change to another one.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is with the column order and most importantly the retsriction that an alias for the rowid column, in your case the **Id** column (*`Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT` defines **Id** as an alias of the rowid column*).

- Note other columns can store any value as per :-

  - > Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
    >   KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.
  - [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Such a column can only store an integer value. `String sql = "INSERT INTO PHOTO VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)";` equates to insert values as per :-

- NULL into the **name** column
- name, as passed, into the **lat** column
- lat, as passed, into the **lon** column
- lon, as passed, into the **image** column
- image, as passed, into the Id column (***bye[]*** cannot be stored in Id column)

You can fix this be either providing the column names or by re-ordering the columns to match the order in which they were defined (the former arguably the better practice).

As such either of the following should fix the issue :-

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PHOTO (Id, name, lat, lon, image) VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)";
```

or :-

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PHOTO VALUES(?,?,?,?,NULL)";
```

Comment: Your detailed answer is much appreciated. It is now fully working. Thank you a lot :)