# sqlite database inserts data in the wrong order sometimes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm working with android studio and I need to insert some data into a database. Sometimes, it works, but sometimes, I get this error. I can't really figure out the difference between the times it works and the times it doesn't.

```
2019-11-09 11:38:34.912 4369-4369/com.example.android.fresh 
D/DatabaseHelper: addData: Adding John Smith to people_table
2019-11-09 11:38:34.913 4369-4369/com.example.android.fresh E/SQLiteLog: 
(20) statement aborts at 5: [INSERT INTO 
people_table(name,amount,contact_no) VALUES (?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
2019-11-09 11:38:34.916 4369-4369/com.example.android.fresh 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=John Smith amount=255.0 contact_no= 1234567890 from {P:4369;U:10178}
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20 SQLITE_MISMATCH)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1613)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1482)
    at com.example.android.fresh.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:51)
    at com.example.android.fresh.createPerson.AddData(createPerson.java:94)
    at com.example.android.fresh.createPerson$1.onClick(createPerson.java:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The relevant code in my database helper class is as follows:

```
private static final String COL1 = "contact_no";
private static final String COL2 = "name";
private static final String COL3 = "amount";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COL1 + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COL3 + " REAL)" ;
    db.execSQL(createTable);

public boolean addData(String contactNo, String contactName, double amount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1, contactNo);
    contentValues.put(COL2, contactName);
    contentValues.put(COL3, amount);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + contactName + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the code in the createPerson class:

```
public void AddData(String contactNo, String contactName, double amount) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(contactNo, contactName, amount);

    if (insertData) {
        check =1;
        toastMessage("Contact Inserted");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

And this is the method call statement:

```
 AddData(contactNumber, contactName, amount);
```

Each one of these is in the order contactNumber, contactName, and amount, but the sqlite error i' m getting is inserting it in the order contactName, amount, and contactNumber. I really can't understand how this is happening.

Comment: better check the definition of your table

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've updated the question w the definition

Comment: Please post the table schema

Comment: @Maik it's in the code for the databasehelper class

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843055/datatype-mismatch-code-20-while-inserting

Comment: see the insert in the answer, it puts a value of null for id

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've checked that question, it doesn't help me because I haven't used bindString, I'm using ContentValues.

Comment: Probably you made changes to the table's design. Uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: What forpas@ said. Have you changed the data types but not dropped and recreated the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 situation where when a data type mismatch will occur, due to SQLite being able to store any type of data in any type of column (with 1 exception and thus the cause/issue).

- you wish to have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), as this explains about the **type** and how it is flexible in comparison to typically databases. It also explains about rowid's aliases and AUTOINCREMENT.

The exception is for a column that is an alias of the rowid column. An alias of the rowid column is defined by using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (specifically INTEGER not INT or not any other value that will result in a derived type of INTEGER).

- Note that AUTOINCREMENT is can be added to (and only to) the definition, although it is inefficient to do so, and rarely needed.

The rowid and therefore an alias thereof MUST contain an integer value (up to 64 bit signed).

As such you are somehow trying to insert a non-integer value into an alias of the rowid, this cannot be the case if the SQL as shown is used to create the table.

As such the SQL has not been successfully run and created the table, but what is very likely the cause is that a previous table exsists that was created using different SQL.

**Simply changing the create SQL will not result in the table being changed**. That is because a database persists (stays there) between runs. As such the **onCreate** method will only be automatically run once for the lifetime of the database.

If you change the schema (the create SQL), then you have to find some way of running the SQL (which would involve dropping the table). The simplest way when developing an App, is to either

1. delete the App's data,
2. to uninstall the App or to
3. increment the version number

   1. this latter option will only work if the onUpgrade drops the table(s) so they can be recreated and invokes the changed SQL (typically by calling onCreate)).

After doing one of the above the App should then be rerun.

- Note the above options will all result in current data being lost. If current data needs to be retained then the process is more complicated and will likely involve ALTER statements to rename tables and statements to copy (INSERT) the data from the original table(s) to the new table(s).

Answer (score 0):

@MikeT already answered this correctly in detail, but nevertheless I'm wondering: why not follow architecture design patterns and implement Android Room?
Using Room, you wouldn't have to worry about this kind of "low level" error. It would tell you what is wrong and that is what it's designed for.
Tip: Let Room do the inserting for you and be happy with persistent data

Comment: I'm not that experienced with android, and this is for a school project where I'm already going way over the complexity level expected of me. I started with room, actually, but I couldn't really figure out some stuff so I just decided to go without it.